# Programatically changing destination view controller's class (swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uistoryboardsegue

I have a maybe slightly unconventional question. I'm working on an app that has two different core data entities (sessions and routines). Subsequently I have two different view controllers in interface builder to fill the attributes of those entities. The thing is that those two entities are identical aside from the fact that I need sessions to have a many to one relationship with a clients entity and routines to have no relationship.

The question is this. Id like to use the same view controller in interface builder for both my session and routine classes, is there a way that I can programatically determine what class the interface builder viewcontroller is assigned to based on a segue identifier? I know it would have to be some sort of `if segue.identifier == "myIdentifier" { 
/*code for changing destination view controller's class*/}` statement but I'm not sure what the code would be, and I also want to hear other suggestions of ways to possibly do this more efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds from your description as if a session could be implemented as a sub-class of a routine.  In that case, your view controller would only need to deal with a routine's display even if it was given a child object (session) to work with.

Comment: It's not possible to change the class of the destination view controller created by a segue.  But why not code your view controller so it can take either a session or a routine object as a property (easy if, as @PhillipMills suggests, you make one a subclass of the other).

Answer (score 0):

The view-controller in your Storyboard is an archived object of a certain class, and you can't just assign it to some other class. (Just as if you have a `String` object and want to assign it to be an `Int` wouldn't work well)

You can check the `destinationViewController` property of the segue within `prepareForSegue:` if it is a certain class like this:

```
if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? MyExpectedVC {
    // do something
}
```

but that is probably not what you want/should do.

I'd go along the lines of what the commenters of your question have said and would suggest that your view controller class implements a configuration method for both your models. Either a separate one for each class like this:

```
func prepareWithSession(session: Session) {/* ... */}
func prepareWithRoutine(session: Routine) {/* ... */}
```

or (imho a bit nicer) create a protocol for all classes that can be displayed by the view controller and have only one method:

```
func prepareWithDisplayable(session: DisplayableType) {/* ... */}
```

where `DisplayableType` would be a protocol that defines all properties that this view controller needs to know about.

You can have custom logic in the view controller that displays some fields only for specific Types. (e.g. sets views hidden for other Types)